# Show twitter timeline in UITableview

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview, twitter

I like to display the timeline in a UITableView, I am using this code to get the tweets:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self gettweets];


}

-(void)gettweets {


    NSString *apiurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=idoodler"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiurl]];


    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *meta = [json valueForKeyPath:@"text"];
    tweets = json;

    NSLog(@"%@",meta);

}
```

My log is showing me the right tweets.

then I am using this to display the tweets in the UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
       //return 0;

    return [tweets count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdenfifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdenfifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdenfifier];
    }

    cell.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];


    return cell;

}
```

I made an IBOutlet in the .h file for the UITableView.I realy don't know how what my mistake is!

Comment: perhaps this might help to you in getting to know about UITableView http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: I tryed it, but it wont work, please check out me question, I added my TableView code

Comment: then you should call [tableView reloadData]; right after the data was fetched

Comment: @art-divin OK, I added the line, but it won't work, can you provide me some code please?

Comment: I cannot understand in what part of your code there is an error you are referring to. Please specify how exactly your code doesn't work, what is setup of your class, in which method do you call download of the feed.

Comment: I've read your edit.. Please read through apple's reference on how UITableView actually works here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html

You should add [tableView reloadData]; right above the line "NSArray *meta = [json valueForKeyPath:@"text"];" and you also have to fill in some data to tweets collection because UITableView's datasource will ask tweets array for some tweets.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look, but can you please take a look on my edited post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better would be to do something like this:

```
NSString *apiurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=idoodler"];
NSError* error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiurl] options: NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error)
{
   // Something went wrong
}
else {
  // Data fetched!
  NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
  NSArray *meta = [json valueForKeyPath:@"text"];
  // Setup your tweets array here!
  [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Also remove the [tableview reloadData]; from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

EDIT:
Also do not forget to set your ViewController as the tableview's datatsource/delegate in interface builder or in your viewDidLoad method like this:

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: OK,must I drag the datasource from the TableView to the ViewController?

Comment: One question, how do I stop the UIRefreshControl?