# Iphone Scrolling Twitter Feed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I would like to know how I can get my recent twitter feed text to scroll across the screen from left to right in an iPhone application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search for horizontal UITableView turned this up:

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView

There are a gazillion UITableView tutorials on the web and a whole bunch of twitter feed tutorials, but here is most of what you need in a similar SO question:

[Show twitter timeline in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279710/show-twitter-timeline-in-uitableview)